# Using DEmanager to fill Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, cloudpage

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="https://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="XXXXXXXX" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="XXXXXXXXX" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="http://example.com/Success" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="http://example.com/Failed" />
            Email: <input type="text" name="Email"><br />
            Id: <input type="text" name="Id"><br />
            First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br />
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName"><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using this to fill it but it is not working, (i've tried using true url in success and error)

It only shows this message:

```
An error has occurred and has been logged by our system. Thank you.
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the action of your form, you need to state the stack you're on. The docos assume S1. For posting/getting all other stacks, you need to state the stack. Salesforce should improve the documentation, but DEManager's not an area of focus:

```
https://cl.s{{myStackNumber}}.exct.net/DEManager.aspx
```